# Order data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase, and I'm going to build a list of item collected from server with following criterias:

- max 10 items
- order by item value (eg. 'count')

this is my code

```
FBRef.orderByChild("count").limitToLast(10).on("child_added", function(snapshot){}
```

and it worked fine, but when a new record inserted, is there a Firebase method that can check and auto update the list if the new item is in top 10 ? Or I need to to it myself ?

```
var FBRef = new Firebase('yours.firebaseio.com');
FBRef.orderByChild("count").limitToLast(5).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();
  var html = "<li>value: " + data.value + " - count: " + data.count + "</li>";
  $("#result").prepend(html);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#inputaddbtn").click(add);
});

function add(){
  var value = $("#inputvalue").val();
  var count = $("#inputcount").val();
  $("#inputcount").val("");
  $("#inputvalue").val("");
  FBRef.push({
    value : value,
    count : count
  })
}
```

Comment: Firebase will fire all the necessary events to keep the 10 items with the highest count in your program. But the relevant code is missing. Can you reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle/jsbin and post the link (and minimal code) here?

Comment: here is what i did [https://jsfiddle.net/dr99ob8g/](https://jsfiddle.net/dr99ob8g/) .I don't want to refresh the whole list so could you give me some suggests ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to monitor more events and handle more arguments to keep the list limited.

As a first step: Firebase will fire a `child_removed` event when an element has been removed from the location or (in your case) falls outside of the query.

You can handle that event to remove the child from the list:

```
var FBRef = new Firebase('yours.firebaseio.com');
var query = FBRef.orderByChild("count").limitToLast(5);
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
    var data = snapshot.val();
  var html = "<li id='key_"+snapshot.key()+"'>value: " + data.value + " - count: " + data.count + "</li>";
  $("#result").prepend(html);
});
query.on("child_removed", function(snapshot){
  $('#key_'+snapshot.key()).remove();
});
```

You'll note that I give the `li` an id when the child is added and then remove the `li` based on that id when Firebase tells me to.

This covers simple adding/removing items. For a complete app that handles all cases, you should also handle `child_changed` and `child_moved`. And you'll probably also want to handle the second argument to the callbacks, which indicates the key of the item that the child needs to go after. But maybe your use-case doesn't require handling these cases, in which case the above is enough.